Custom U-Boot writes to environment file but cannot read from it
I am trying to boot up a virtualized machine using QEMU. I have created a raw disk image named disk.img. It contains two partitions: the first being a FAT32 bootable partition and the second being a default Linux partition. I am trying to add this disk to my emulated machine using QEMU. This is the command I use:
sudo qemu-system-riscv64 -m 2G -nographic -machine virt -smp 8 \
-bios /home/isaiahs/riscv/riscv/opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_payload.elf \
-drive file=disk.img,format=raw,id=hd0 \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \

When starting the machine I run the command setenv foo bar and then saveenv and I get the message:
Saving Environment to FAT... OK.

When I mount the FAT partition to /mnt I can see that the uboot.env file was written to disk by uboot and it contains foo=bar. However, when starting the emulated machine up again the machine does not contain the env variable foo=bar. Why might this be?
I also get this message from U-Boot:
Loading Environment from FAT... ** Bad device specification virtio 0 **

I modified U-Boot using make menuconfig to have these options:
make qemu-riscv64_smode_defconfig


Unset CONFIG_ENV_IS_NOWHERE
CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FAT=y
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_INTERFACE="virtio"
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_DEVICE_AND_PART="0:1"
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_FILE="uboot.env"

When the machine boots I expect to be able to do printenv foo and it display foo=bar but that is not happening, even though foo=bar was written by U-Boot to uboot.env file within the FAT partition of the disk. U-Boot is not reading from this uboot.env and I am not sure why.
I found that I am able to load the environment from the virtio disk manually in the U-Boot command line with the following commands:
=> printenv foo 
## Error: "foo" not defined 
=> fatload virtio 0:1 ${loadaddr} uboot.env 
131072 bytes read in 3 ms (41.7 MiB/s) 
=> env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize} 
=> printenv foo 
foo=bar 


As shown in the log, virtio is not supported as an interface for environment. Extending support to include this would be much appreciated. Otherwise, emulate an mmc device as done and tested on hardware.

@TomRini I found that I am able to load the environment from the virtio disk manually in the uboot command line with the following commands:
=> printenv foo
## Error: "foo" not defined
=> fatload virtio 0:1 ${loadaddr} uboot.env
131072 bytes read in 3 ms (41.7 MiB/s)
=> env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize}
=> printenv foo
foo=bar

If virtio is not supported as an interface for environment how can I manually load this environment from the virtio disk?

Because "load a file from virtio" is supported and "read environment from a memory location" is supported. Those are both done at the command line, as you noted in your follow-up answer.
Looking harder, it seems likely that you need commit 4f652182a0777085eb9022648c33c5fd8356a0de to address your problem.

I have solved this issue. Using make menuconfig for U-Boot I added fatload virtio 0:1 ${loadaddr} uboot.env; env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize} to the preboot command in boot options -> enable preboot. Seems like a hacky solution so I'm still open to insight on why it didn't load in the first place without having to execute these commands.

@TomRini is one of the key maintainers of U-Boot project, so I would listen to what he says.

I was struggling with same issue with Yocto when running QEMU through Yocto's runqemu command.
Updating U-Boot to 2024.07 or newer should fix your issue as it contains the commit 4f652182a0777085eb9022648c33c5fd8356a0de mentioned by @TomRini.
